# network_site_url() from wp-login page WordPress not working

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$message = __('Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account:') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= network_home_url( '/' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= __('If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= __('To reset your password, visit the following address:') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n";
```

The email I got link without wp-login.php

> Someone requested that the password be reset for the following
>   account:
>
> http://localhost.com/
>
> Username: test12
>
> If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.
>
> To reset your password, visit the following address:
>
> `<http://localhost.com?action=rp&key=$P$Btka6BPNxTtMA2ohCF4bLMwaQ0pXHc/&login=test12>`

I debugged and found that system is checking if link having wp-login.php then remove this file name from link and send mail. Is there any file in which we can check?

Comment: Looks like a known bug: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/possible-bug-bad-network_home_url-on-multisite-giving-wp-its-own-directory

Comment: For completeness, can you post the raw email? (just the part relative to `$message`)

Comment: Also, [check this comment](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21095#comment:9) and the following after that.

Comment: @brasofilo, I have mentioned the contents of email, but wp-login.php is missing in link

Comment: I debugged and found that file name having hypen , system is removing whole filename and appending rest of the data and sending mail. If file name having underscore then system is sending correct link, but not for hypen

Comment: So, the email is arriving with `<http://...>` instead of `<a href>link</a>`? . . . What file name with hyphen? Are you modifying the file `wp-login.php` in any fashion? Or are you working with your own code in `functions.php` or custom plugin? . . . . ***Please***, [edit] the question to go adding new info, instead of here in comments.

Comment: Nopes, a new file class-wp-modal-login.php having the code in plugins/wp-modal-login/includes/class-wp-modal-login.php

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me the solution was to parse mail as html. I added this into functions and it works now.

```
function html_laiskai(){
    return "text/html";
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','html_laiskai' );
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'html_email_encode_body' );
function html_email_encode_body( $mail ) {
    $mail['message'] = str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $mail['message']);
    return $mail;
}
```

First function changes header of all emails to `text/html`.
Second function changes the `\r\n` line breaks for `<br />` ones.